# Category tree generating takes too much time

Tags: magento-1.7, category-tree, flat-catalog

StackExchange! I've faced big problem with category tree generating process. I run

```
$flat = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_flat');
$categories = $flat->getCategories($parentCategoryId, 4, false, false, true);
```

and it takes 4 minutes. As I understand the query is that slow because of left join of core_url_rewrite table (I have 86515 records there).

Has Magento team fixed the issue with catalog URL rewrites in later versions of platform (now I'm working with sites on Magento 1.7 and I know that it need to be upgraded) or I'm doing something wrong?